# Run C++ code on Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I've setup VS Code for C++, I made a task for building and one for running, here is my `tasks.json` file:

```
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "build",
        "command": "g++",
        "isShellCommand": true,
        "showOutput": "always",
        "args": ["-g", "${workspaceRoot}/C++/main.cpp"],
        "isBuildCommand": true
    },{
        "taskName": "run",
        "command": "${workspaceRoot}/a.out",
        "showOutput": "always",
        "isShellCommand": true,
        "echoCommand": true
    }
]
```

building works well and such, but whenever I run the `run` task VS Code does nothing at all, just a foward slash appears spinning on the lower left corner, and the output says `running command$ /home/vitor/Documentos/code/a.out` but doesn't accept nothing as input or such.

How I should set my `tasks.json` file for running C++ inside VS Code?

PS: Code runs normally on terminal